Envelope conditional expectation uniform distribution question
Question: There are two envelopes, each of which has a check for a Unif(0, 1) amount of money,
measured in thousands of dollars. The amounts in the two envelopes are independent.
You get to choose an envelope and open it, and then you can either keep that amount
or switch to the other envelope and get whatever amount is in that envelope.
Suppose that you use the following strategy: choose an envelope and open it. If you
observe U, then stick with that envelope with probability U, and switch to the other
envelope with probability 1 − U.
(a) Find the probability that you get the larger of the two amounts.
(b) Find the expected value of what you will receive.
For part a), let's say that we pick from envelope 1 always WLOG and $U_1$ represents the amount in envelope 1 and $U_2$ represents the amount in envelope 2. I know how to do part a) when you condition on $U_1 = u_1$. However, I am not sure how to continure with the following reasoning:

Let $P(L)$ be the probability of getting the larger of the two amounts.Then there only 2 ways that this can happen - $P(L) = P(S, U_1>U_2) + P(S^C, U_1<U_2)$ where $S$ means you stick (and so $S^C$ means you switch) and $U_1>U_2$ means that the amount in envelope 1 is greater than envelope 2.
now this is the part I am struggling on. We can split both terms, e.g. consider  $P(S, U_1>U_2)$  as an example, as $P(S, U_1>U_2) = P(S|U_1>U_2)P(U_1>U_2)$ by Bayes. $P(U_1>U_2) = \frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry but I don't know how to deal with the $P(S|U_1>U_2)$ term. We are given that $P(S) = U_1$ in the question but I don't how to work out $P(S|U_1>U_2)$.

For part b), I now understand how to solve it like this: $E[V|U_1=u_1]=(1−u_1)(\frac{1}{2})+u_1(u_1)=\frac{1}{2}−\frac{u_1}{2}+u_1^2$ and then you would take expectation again. However, I tried to do it by conditioning on $U_1<U_2$ and I couldn't get it to work.
I had the following idea in mind, but don't know how to proceed with it as I am facing a similar issue to part a), but also I am not sure if I am taking care of the conditional expectations correctly:

We condition on four possible cases - you stick with $U_1$ and $U_1>U_2$, you switch to $U_2$ and $U_1>U_2$, you stick with $U_1$ and $U_1<U_2$ and you switch to $U_2$ and $U_1<U_2$ i.e. $E(V) = E(V|S, U_1>U_2)P(S, U_1>U_2) + E(V|S^C, U_1>U_2)P(S^C, U_1>U_2) + E(V|S, U_1<U_2)P(S, U_1<U_2) + E(V|S^C, U_1<U_2)P(S^C, U_1<U_2)$. $V$ is the value you get.
As mentioned before, I don't know how to evaluate the probabilities (similar problem to part a)). For the conditional expectations, I evaluated them in this way (I will just do it for one of them since the others are similar): $E(V|S,U_1>U_2) = E(U_1|S,U_1>U_2) = \frac{1+U_2}{2}$ (since we know $U_1>U_2$).
Another separate point (kind of related to the method above) is that Adam's law says that in general if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then $E(E(Y|X)) = E(Y)$. In this case why can't we get $E(V)$ by doing $E(V) = E(E(V|S,U_1>U_2)) = E(\frac{1+U_2}{2}) = \frac{3}{4}$?

I know it's a lot of questions and I appreciate taking the time to read this post. Conditional expectation just confuses me a lot :(
By the way the answer to a) is $\frac{2}{3}$ and the answer to b) is $\frac{7}{12}$

Let $X$ be a binary random variable independent of $U_2$ such that $X\sim\textrm{Bernoulli}(U_1)$, that is $P(X=1|U_1)=U_1$ and $P(X=0|U_1)=1-U_1$. The final prize is $Y=U_1X+U_2(1-X)$. For (a): we need to compute $P(Y=\max(U_1,U_2))$. We see
$$P(Y=\max(U_1,U_2))=\frac{1}{2}(P(Y=U_1|U_1>U_2)+P(Y=U_2|U_1\leq U_2))$$
and $P(Y=U_1|U_1>U_2)=\frac{P(Y=U_1,U_1>U_2)}{P(U_1>U_2)}=2P(Y=U_1,U_1>U_2)$. Now $\{Y=U_1\}=\{X=1\}$ so $P(Y=U_1,U_1>U_2)=P(X=1,U_1>U_2)$ and
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X=1,U_1>U_2)&=\int_{[0,1]}P(X=1,U_1>u_2)du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}E[P(X=1|U_1)\mathbf{1}_{\{U_1>u_2\}}]du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}E[U_1\mathbf{1}_{\{U_1>u_2\}}]du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{(u_2,1]}u_1du_1du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1-u_2^2}{2}du_2\\
&=\frac{1}{3}
\end{aligned}$$
So $P(Y=U_1|U_1>U_2)=2/3$. Equivalently $P(Y=U_2|U_2\geq U_1)=\frac{P(Y=U_2,U_2\geq U_1)}{P(U_2\geq U_1)}=2P(X=0,U_2\geq U_1)$ and
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X=0,U_2\geq U_1)&=\int_{[0,1]}P(X=0,u_2\geq U_1)du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}E[P(X=0|U_1)\mathbf{1}_{\{u_2\geq U_1\}}]du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}E[(1-U_1)\mathbf{1}_{\{u_2\geq U_1\}}]du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,u_2]}(1-u_1)du_1du_2\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{2u_2-u_2^2}{2}du_2\\
&=\frac{1}{3}
\end{aligned}$$
So again $P(Y=U_2|U_2\geq U_1)=2/3$. We conclude $P(Y=\max(U_1,U_2))=2/3$. For (b):
$$E[Y]=E[U_1X]+E[U_2](1-E[X])=E[U_1^2]+1/4=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{7}{12}$$
because $X\perp U_2$, $E[X|U_1]=U_1$ and $E[X]=E[E[X|U_1]]=E[U_1]=1/2$.
